# Pivot a dataframe with two columns (where a column has duplicate values)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I am trying to pivot my current two column dataframe which currently looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ0zp.png)

I want to pivot this and the final dataframe should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWjGy.png)

The final output should have all the values under the column names

I tried this after adding a new column 'index' in the dataframe, but getting Nan values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhsEF.png)

Comment: please read the duplicate in detail, and if still in need of help, provide a fully reproducible example, the expected output, your code and a description of how this fails